# Remove data from old realm during Realm database migration

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm, realm-migration

So I'm in the situation where I need to migrate one of the models in my database. I have added a `DateTimeOffset` field to the model that will contain a date for my `Recommendation` model that currently doesn't exist in the database. So there is no way to populate the new field from the existing data.

In my migration callback I want a blank slate for the `Recommendation` model and all of it's sub models (it's composed of a few classes). So I can fetch a fresh data set of Recommendations from my web-api with the new field. When I attempt to purge the old database of all the existing model data I get an exception.

> Realms.Exceptions.RealmInvalidTransactionException
>
> Can't perform transactions on read-only Realms.

How do I achieve the above?

Here's the relevant code for my migration callback.

```
        var config = new RealmConfiguration("salt.realm");
        config.SchemaVersion = 2;
        config.MigrationCallback = (migration, oldSchemaVersion) =>
        {
            Settings.UpdateDateRecommendationsUtc = DateTime.MinValue;

            migration.OldRealm.Write(() => 
            { 
                migration.OldRealm.RemoveAll("RecDataString");
                migration.OldRealm.RemoveAll("RecChart");
                migration.OldRealm.RemoveAll("RecSummary");
                migration.OldRealm.RemoveAll("RecTickerSymbol");
                migration.OldRealm.RemoveAll("Recommendation");
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not want any data for those five `RealmObject`s to be preserved during the migration, `RemoveAll` from the `NewRealm` as the data will already be available in the NewRealm with either the default values for added properties or missing properties for those that were removed.

You only need the `OldRealm` data during the migration if you need to access "old" properties and perform some type of data transformation on it and update the `NewRealm` with it...

```
migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<POCO>();
await UpdateRecommendationFromYourWebApi();
```

Note: Since you are adding a `DateTimeOffset`, you might want to take note of a current bug that is setting the default value to "1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM +00:00" vs. "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM +00:00"

Re: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/1225

Comment: Hi SushiHangover, you're right and almost correct, I've figured it out will post an updated answer. Don't need to NewRealm.Write() part as it turns out the MigrationCallback is a Write transaction itself. Also it doesn't like the RemoveAll("") call. It throws a RealmException complaining that Realm.RemoveRange() expects an IQueryable from .All or something like. I guess it uses Realm.RemoveRange() under the hood. See my updated answer. Also thank you for the heads up on the DateTimeOffset bug!!!

Comment: @MarkSilver I did that from memory and just cut/pasted your code..., use `migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<POCO>();` instead of `RemoveRange`

Comment: I've tested it with the `RemoveAll<T>()` type parameter function and it works. It seems it's just the dynamic function it doesn't like `RemoveAll("className")` will throw an exception. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So as @SushiHangover correctly stated I should have been operating on the newRealm rather than the oldRealm. As I am concerned with removed the RealmObjects of the new Realm.
No write transaction required as `config.MigrationCallback` is already a write transaction itself.
I couldn't get `RemoveAll("className")` to work it throws an exception, this is the working solution I have currently.

```
        var config = new RealmConfiguration("salt.realm");
        config.SchemaVersion = 1;
        config.MigrationCallback = (migration, oldSchemaVersion) =>
        {
            Settings.UpdateDateRecommendationsUtc = DateTime.MinValue;

            migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<Recommendation>();
            migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<RecDataString>();
            migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<RecChart>();
            migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<RecSummary>();
            migration.NewRealm.RemoveAll<RecTickerSymbol>();
        };
```